# Lambda function using paramiko SSH Client unable to connect to EC2 in the same subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am writing this lambda function that uses **paramiko.SSHClient()** to connect to an EC2 instance that is located in the same Account / VPC / subnet.

The connection method is using the old user and password authentication method (no pass key involved) because the EC2 prohibits other authentication methods.

The method call goes as follows:

```
    c = paramiko.SSHClient()
    c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    c.connect(server, port, username=username, password=password, pkey=None)
```

It works without any error when I run the Python code from my own machine. But when I deploy the code to Lambda, it gives me "[Error 16] Device or resource busy".

```
[ERROR] OSError: [Errno 16] Device or resource busy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 36, in lambda_handler
    c.connect(server, port, username=username, password=password, pkey=None)
  File "/var/task/paramiko/client.py", line 377, in connect
    to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
  File "/var/task/paramiko/client.py", line 202, in _families_and_addresses
    addrinfos = socket.getaddrinfo(
  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.12/socket.py", line 963, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):END RequestId: ....
```

The messagem doesn´t seem to be a network error, but rather an OS Error (as the message implies).

It seems to me that when the error raises, the SSHClient hasn´t started the connection processes yet so, it suggests a memory or IO issue inside the lambda machines.

I´ve checked basic stuff (Security Groups, Outbound rules, permissions, etc.) and they are all OK. Also, if I change the "server" parameter and give them a fake server, the message is still the same. So it shows the message is not related to socket connection, but to OS resource.

As for the Security Group, there is an Outbound rule in the lambda config that allows ALL protocols and ALL ports to send to any destination in 10.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12.
Both Lambda and EC2 are in the same subnet and inside the above range.

UPDATE:
Here is another information.
I´ve put an extra code to try and debug things.
So I tried to connect using the more low-level socket method.
Tried to connect to the same server, and port, but it gives me:

```
[Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: I think you may be misreading the symptoms. If you change the server parameter and the symptoms are the same then that would seem to indicate a network connectivity issue more than anything else. You said that the security groups are all OK, but they may not be. Include them in your post.

Comment: I´m not sure it is ok to print my security groups here, but I can describe them. There is an Outbound rule in the lambda config that allows ALL protocols and ALL ports to send to any destination in 10.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0.0/16, 172.16.0.0/12. My subnet is inside that range.

Comment: Your EC2 instance security group needs inbound port 22 from the Lambda function's security group.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. In fact the EC2 rules did not allow port 22 coming from Lambda. I fixed it, but it still not OK. Same problem.

Comment: And what is the configuration of the security group on the EC2 instance? Also, is the Lambda function configured to connect to the VPC? You should also be connecting to the **private IP address** (which would be different to how you connect from your own machine).

Comment: John, the SG on the EC2 was not allowing incoming SSH connection from the lambda. But now I fixed that and the problem continues. The connection is being made through private IP address (and also tried private DNS).

Answer (score 0):

I came to a conclusion that Lambda is not the intended way of doing it.

As a solution, I shifted to AWS System Manager.

You will need a role with a policy allowing the action `ssm:sendComand`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
            "ssm:SendCommand"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]

}
```

And trusting `ssm.amazonaws.com` to assumeRole.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "Service": ["ssm.amazonaws.com"]
        },
        "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole"
        ]
    }
}
```

After that, you will need to:

1. Create a Document (which is the decription of the Command you want to run).
2. Run the command (via Console, or CLI), or
3. (optional) If you want to automate things a little bit, create a **Management Window** and you can schedule tasks to run the command you created in step 1.

Notes:

The service runs commands as **root** user, so be carefull. "With great power comes great responsibility"

Also, you can run **ANY** command or script as if you were logged in the EC2 instance. Anything you can do it with the command line, as root, you can do via AWS System Manager. Just update the Document you made in step 1.